# Changing model to polymorphic and maintain relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have 2 models, `Payment` and `Consultation`.  Previously `Payment` belonged to `Consultation` and had `consultation_id` as an attribute.

I've now made the relationship polymorphic but I'd still like to be able to call `.consultation` on a `Payment`.  **Is this possible through a `belongs_to` association?**

I tried the following with no luck:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :paymentable, optional: true, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :consultation, class_name: "Consultation"
end
```

Comment: Instead of `consulation_id` now you have `paymentable_id: 1, paymentable_type: Consulation` ?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to call `.consultation` on a `Payment`.  You need to modify the relationships:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :paymentable, optional: true, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :consultation, class_name: "Consultation", foreign_key: :paymentable_id
end
```

Comment: It works ok-ish. If the paymentable type is something else than Consulation, it will return it as consulation. Probably not what you want. With `belongs_to` the paymentable_type is not used, it will just query by id.